# Finding an integer solution for $(x,y)$ that satisfies the given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elliptic-curves

> $$(y+6)^3 - (y+24)=x^2$$

I need an integer solution for (x,y) such that it satisfies the above equation. I tried analytical ways but couldn't find any solution. Online plotting tools (like Desmos) could also not get a solution up to y=36. So, it would be wonderful if somebody could come up with a solution where both x and y are positive integers (either methodically or by chance).

Actually, any solution (x,y) would actually satisfy this nested-radical given by:

> $$y=\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[3]{x^2+\sqrt[3]{x^3+\sqrt[3]{x^4+\sqrt[3]{x^5...}}}}}$$

Comment: See [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/139904/d/1): no integer points.

Comment: If you write $w = y + 6$, your equation becomes $$w^3 - w - 18 = x^2,$$ which is the Weierstrass form of your elliptic curve. Try working with that.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that it falls under the tag of elliptic curves. Heard this term for the first time and will now study that. Thank you.